# How to hide the DiscordAPIError (discord.js) (node.js)

Tags: node.js, exception, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord bot.
Right now i'm trying to make a delete all roles command, but I don't like the errors in the console about the **@everyone** and the roles upper than the bot role.
Any solution to change the message to something like **The {role} role couldn't be deleted,** or to entirely hide it?

Example:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Role
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\SapphireNuker JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\SapphireNuker JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/guilds/835119368807383091/roles/835119368807383091',
  code: 50028,
  httpStatus: 400
}
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\SapphireNuker JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\SapphireNuker JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/guilds/835119368807383091/roles/859000573138305026',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403
}
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\SapphireNuker JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\SapphireNuker JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/guilds/835119368807383091/roles/859043233375977494',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

The code I am using:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(roles => {

   roles.delete()
   .then(deleted => console.log(`Deleted role ${deleted.name}`))
   .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Instead of trying to hide errors, try to fix them. The Bot doesnt have enough permissions. Try giving your bot admin permissions and keeping it on the top of the role hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.catch()` or `try/catch`. The thing about try catch is that it doesn’t catch asynchronous errors. The way to do promise.catch is like this:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(async roles => {  
roles.delete()
   .then(deleted => console.log(`Deleted role ${deleted.name}`))
.catch(console.error);
})
```

I don’t understand why your .catch didn’t work before, unless you’re logging it for some reason, and it’s not ending your node process. Here is another way to stop error:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(async roles => {  
try {
await (roles.delete()
   .then(deleted => console.log(`Deleted role ${deleted.name}`)))
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
})
```

It’s best if you use the first one however. But if you don’t want anything to happen on error, just use `return` instead of console.error